# iOS - rectangle appears after tapping button

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have two `UIButtons` and a strange rectangle appears when tapping one of them. I don't know why. I set the images as background images on the button and it worked fine until now.

What I changed now is that I set each button `isSelected` property and before I did not
Like this:

```
thumbsDownButton.isSelected = true 
thumbsUpButton.isSelected = false
```

[image]
[image]

Obviously what I want is for that rectangle to go away

Comment: Well, as I said before it worked fine, but now I added isSelected for automation purposes and UITests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style was set to `System`. Setting it to `Custom` fixed the problem and the rectangle is not appearing anymore. I set it from the xib (if it makes any difference)

Answer (score 0):

Add this Code

```
thumbsDownButton.tintColor = UIColor.white
```

Comment: This wouldn't work since I use tint color to change the buttons color to make it red

Answer (score 0):

It seems your frame may be calculated in the wrong way.
Try to use this one to check it.

```
button.clipToBounds = true
```

Please share more code related of initializing and setting up the frame of your view.

Comment: The frame is set in the xib

Comment: And I changed clipToBounds to true and now the rectangle is just smaller, but still there